# Translucent UITableViewCell has no borders

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios6, border

I created a UITableView. I gave it a background image like this:

```
UIImageView *imageview1 = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
imageview1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blood2.gif"];
evc.tableView.backgroundView = imageview1;
```

And then I made the cells translucent by changing them in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method:

```
UIView *backgrView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
backgrView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:1 alpha:0.7];

cell.backgroundView = backgrView;
```

But now there are no borders around the UITableViewCells anymore. I already set the separatorColor to black but the borders won't show up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with this

> [cell.contentView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
>       [cell.contentView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];

Comment: Works fine. Thanks. But can you tell me how to get the old "rounded rect"-style of the normal grouped tableviewcells back ? So that the top and bottom cells get rounded corners and that there is only one line between 2 cells ? That would be great.

Comment: I would Use CALayer for that and setCornerRadius. I would really need to see your view frames to understand more.